# Rails simple loop conditions

Tags: loops, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Absolute rails newb here.

For my index view, how would I change the loop conditions for `<% @complaints.each do |complaint| %>` to do something like `where @complaint.user_id == current_user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to do this in the controller, but in any case in the view it's something like:

```
<% @complaints.where(user_id: current_user).each do |complaint| %>
```